# Active directory - get all domain controllers

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I have this AD server "adserver.europe.company.com".

I know there are some ... "branches". "DC=europe,DC=company,DC=com","DC=africa,DC=company,DC=com", "DC=asia,DC=company,dc=com" etc.

If I query the server (using the DirectorySearcher class) with SearchScope = OneLevel and an empty base asking only for the distinguishedName I get only entries ending in "DC=europe,DC=company,DC=com".

However, if I use "DC=africa,DC=company,DC=com" as base, I do get the entries ending in "DC=africa,DC=company,DC=com".

How can I get all the branches for this AD server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to obtain all the partitions this way:

```
DirectoryContext aContext = new DirectoryContext( DirectoryContextType.DirectoryServer, LDAPServer, LDAPUser, LDAPPassword );
Forest aForest = Forest.GetForest( aContext );
foreach ( ApplicationPartition aPartition in aForest.ApplicationPartitions )
{
    ...
}
```